# Is there any case where a module needs to implement a class using ServiceProviderInterface?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

Drupal defines the [CoreServiceProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!CoreServiceProvider.php/class/CoreServiceProvider/8) class which is used to add the twig, twig.loader.filesystem, and module_handler services.

Since the Drupal 8 way to register a service from a module is using the .services.yaml file, is there any case where a class similar to `CoreServiceProvider` should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no: The Twig service registration is written by [Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/) himself.  Nobody will probably need to write anything as complex as Twig to necessitate this level of complexity in the service registration.
The module handler is just fanciness: An override for the module handler could have been written during install time.

Unless you are writing an install profile which uses a service, you won't face this problem.